# Flutter app base apk doesn't exist error upon launching app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm having an error upon launching a flutter app on my phone for debug only for android. It was working perfectly and now I'm getting this error upon lauching:-

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
✓ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install D:\flutter\illuminate\illuminate\illuminate\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: 
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.illuminate.comcrop-
4axwxmIT5fpdidhVYjy4tQ==: Package /data/app/com.illuminate.comcrop-4axwxmIT5fpdidhVYjy4tQ==/base.apk code 
is missing]
```

This what I see on debug console. How do I get my app working again?

> Update

Output for flutter doctor

```
PS D:\flutter\illuminate> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.20.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version      
    10.0.18362.900], locale en-IN)
 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version    29.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found
```

Comment: Did you uninstall it completely before installing it again? What is the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: Yes I did uninstall and run it.

Comment: Can you run `flutter clean` and check if the issue still persists?

Comment: Yes, It did help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, those issues are fixed by running `flutter clean` command.